# Hello world minitest cli example

Tags: ruby, bash, command-line-interface, minitest

Given the following directory structure:

```
➜  ~/D/w/t/foo  tree .
.
├── app.rb
├── foo.rb
└── test
    └── test_foo.rb

1 directory, 3 files
```

If I run `app.rb` I get the classic "Hello world!" response.

```
➜  ~/D/w/t/foo  ruby app.rb
"Hello world!"
```

Taking a look inside `app.rb` and `foo.rb`:

```
➜  ~/D/w/t/foo  cat app.rb
require_relative 'foo.rb'

Foo.new.bar

➜  ~/D/w/t/foo  cat foo.rb
class Foo
  def bar
    p "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

How would I would I test my `Foo` class with minitest from the commandline?

I know that it has something to do with the `ruby -Ilib` command but I'm not sure what the exact switches and flags are, and also I'm not sure what to put inside of `test_foo.rb`. I'm also not sure if my directory stucture is set up right. Maybe `foo.rb` needs to go inside of a `lib` directory?

Would love you guidance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run minitest tests just like ruby files. Just install minitest, write a test, and run like you would a ruby script:

install minitest:

```
➜  ~/D/w/t/hello-minitest  gem install minitest
Successfully installed minitest-5.9.1
Parsing documentation for minitest-5.9.1
Done installing documentation for minitest after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
➜  ~/D/w/t/hello-minitest  tree .
.
├── app.rb
├── foo.rb
└── test
    └── test_foo.rb
```

write foo.rb:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    p "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

write test:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative '../foo.rb'

class TestFoo < Minitest::Test
  def test_it_works
    assert_equal 1, 1
  end

  def test_bar
    assert_equal Foo.new.bar, "Hello world!"
  end
end
```

run test like ruby script:

```
➜  ~/D/w/t/hello-minitest  ruby test/test_foo.rb
Run options: --seed 56777

# Running:

"Hello world!"
..

Finished in 0.001085s, 1843.3179 runs/s, 1843.3179 assertions/s.

2 runs, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```